# ParseCrashReporting - Apple Mach-O Linker Error after enabling it

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

I had Parse iOS SDK v1.2.20 on my app. After updating it to the latest version (v1.8.0), I got 23 Apple Mach-O Linker errors.

The only thing I did is deleted the Parse.framework file and replaced it with the new `Parse.framework` and `Bolts.framework`. I don't understand why I get so many errors. They all start with "_sqlite3". If I click any error, it shows me a detailed page, which starts with `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` Does someone know what is going wrong?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Linking libstdc++6.0.9.dylib and libsqlite3.0.dylib worked for me.  It could be the flag, but I doubt it.  Try adding libstdc and see if it works.

Comment: Yeah. The app does not show up any errors but te crashes do not show up on Parse's Dashboard. Does it happens to you?

Comment: Yes, that's happening to me to for some reason.  The docs vaguely explain that you have you upload some symbol files (like dysm) for crash reporting to work properly.

Comment: libstdc++6.0.9.dylib resolved most of my errors. Why is that? **EDIT** Looks like they forgot to put that in the Parse docs.

Comment: Confirming that add libstdc++6.0.9.dylib worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Probably should be checkmarked as the solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Double check that you're importing the correct libraries - see below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Build Phases section of your project, add libsqlite3.dylib to you "Link Binary With Libraries" section. Parse likely has an updated setup doc you could consult too.

Comment: Shouldn't the frameworks import sqlite3, not the app?

Comment: @jshier - It partially worked. Now I have less errors than before. The errors left have in common the ``ParseCrashReporting`` text, so I guess it has to do with that. Also, if I removed the code ``[ParseCrashReporting enable]`` from the ``AppDelegate.m`` I get no errors.

Comment: @Droppy Parse's setup instructions want you to link it manually, so unfortunately not. It would probably be linked automatically if you used CocoaPods or something.

Comment: @alvarolopez Did you download and install the ParseCrashReporting framework?

Comment: @jshier - Yes, I did. I think the errors are coming from the flags I used or should use. I am currently using -force_load, -lc++ and including a static element (libPayPalMobile.a).