# Parse in Xcode using Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, linker-errors

I am trying to implement Parse in my Xcode project. However, when I add the frameworks, I cannot run my app because I have 9 different Mach-O Linker errors.

I know that I can just remove the frameworks to get rid of the errors, but I still want to use Parse.

Did I do something wrong when adding the frameworks? I just dragged them over and tried once not "copying if needed" and the other time I did. I still get the same errors. Here is a snapshot of what the errors look like:

[image]

EDIT: I added libstdc++6.0.9.dylib and almost all my errors were fixed, but I still get the nine errors shown in the picture!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ParseCrashReporting - Apple Mach-O Linker Error after enabling it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447648/parsecrashreporting-apple-mach-o-linker-error-after-enabling-it)

Comment: @luk2302 different symbols; different solution. It's not a dupe of that question.

Comment: It was a mixture of a hint and a possible duplicate - it fixed it for me when I had the issue a month ago

Comment: Show the full linker command line.

Comment: Why have you changed your picture to show different error messages?

Comment: Sorry I was about to put that in the edit, I added libstdc++6.0.9.dylib and most my errors were fixed... However these 9 errors stayed @Droppy

Comment: OK; well don't be so specific about the version; remove that `.dylib` and specify `-lstdc++` in the *Other Linker Flags*.  The remaining symbols are part of the Facebook SDK by the look of them.

Comment: @Droppy Thanks for all your help! I ended up specifying -lstdc++ in the Other Linker Flags and removing the framework ParseFacebookUtils.framework and that cleared up the rest of my issues, Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have added all the required libraries (not only the ones from the Parse SDK, but also those required for the SDK itself)?

**Please check against the following list:**

• AudioToolbox.framework

• CFNetwork.framework

• CoreGraphics.framework

• CoreLocation.framework

• QuartzCore.framework

• Security.framework

• StoreKit.framework

• SystemConfiguration.framework

• libz.dylib

• libsqlite3.dylib

**If you're using the -ObjC linker flag required by some third-party libraries, add these as well:**

• Accounts.framework

• Social.framework

Also, see [this quickstart guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing) from Parse (for detailed information) and check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27464780/4988014)

Especially, **make sure you have added all the lib.libraries** that are required by the above list, seems like you have forgotten some of them.

Comment: Yes, I have all of those frameworks added but still have the same error @ericschanet

Comment: @Droppy yes C++ sorry I am fairly new to objective C (++)

Comment: @eric if you read the [downloads/changelog](https://parse.com/docs/downloads) of Parse SDK you'll see that MobileCoreServices is no longer __required__ as you put. As of June 24 2015. Please edit your answer to reflect the changes for accountability to future question seekers.

Answer (score 0):

I think There might be some problem in your **SDK** i.e -

**Reason 1**- You might have imported .m file somewhere .

**Reason 2**- The dependencies & configuration are not correctly configured .